# Strapi route returning 404

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, strapi

I have a react app with a strapi backend. I have a cart that I'm trying to connect to Stripe.

In my backend I have created a new route in strapi

```
'use strict';
// @ts-ignore
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_51H");

const { createCoreRouter } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreRouter('api::order.order');

module.exports = {
    routes: [
        {
            method: "POST",
            path: "/orders/payment",
            handler: "order.setUpStripe"
        }
    ]
}
```

And then a setUpStripe function

```
"use strict";
// @ts-ignore
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_51H");

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = {
    ...createCoreController("api::order.order"),
    setUpStripe: async (ctx) => {
        console.log('here')
        let total = ''; // Initialize total as a numeric value
        let validatedCart = [];
        let receiptCart = [];

        const { cart } = ctx.request.body;

        await Promise.all(cart.map(async (font) => {
            try {
                const validatedProduct = await strapi.db.query('api::font.font').findOne({
                    where: { id: font.id }
                });

                if (validatedProduct) {
                    validatedCart.push(validatedProduct);
                    receiptCart.push({
                        id: font.id
                    });
                }
            } catch (error) {
            }
        }));

        total = validatedCart.reduce((acc, { price }) => acc + price, 0);

        try {
            const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
                amount: total,
                currency: 'usd',
                metadata: { cart: JSON.stringify(receiptCart) },
                payment_method_types: ['card']
            });

            // Send a response back to the client
            ctx.send({
                paymentIntent,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            ctx.send({
                error: true,
                message: 'Error in processing payment',
                details: error.message,
            });
        }
    }
};
```

This isn't working.

If I try this route in a browser

```
http://localhost:1337/api/orders/payment
```

I get

> { "data": null,
> "error": { "status":404, "name": "NotFoundError",
> "message": "Not Found", "details": {} }
> }

I expect to be able to view this address in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Your Strapi endpoint uses the `POST` HTTP method. Opening that URL/route in a browser will use the `GET` HTTP method, and therefore is expected to `404`.

If you expect to be able to access that route directly in the browser you will need to change the methods to `GET`.